# How to open bootstrap modal in ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to open bootstrap modal through jquery. I know ajax in running to success as it throws alerts. But cannot open modal. These are my code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url() . 'index.php/application/requestCode'; ?>",
    data: {
        'apiName': apiName,
        'api': api,
        'hotel': hotel,
        'payment':payment,
        'template': template
    },
    success: function(msg)
    {
        $("#getCodeModal").modal("toggle");
        $("#getCode").html(msg);
    }
});
```

And my modal HTML is:

```
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="getCodeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> API CODE </h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body" id="getCode" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
          //ajax success content here.
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

In error in console: modal is not a function.

Comment: And what happens? Some errors in console?

Comment: try putting opening bracket in one line with ``success: function(msg)``

Comment: Did you import `bootstrap.js`?

Comment: yes. sure i imported it. It show through data-attribute.

Comment: I Solved the error. It was that jquery library was imported after the bootstrap.js .

Answer (score 26):

try with this

```
success: function(resp){
    $("#getCode").html(resp);
    $("#getCodeModal").modal('show');
}
```

Comment: only `$("#getCodeModal").modal('show');` is needed inside success function. @Shakil no content in the model is displayed when put `$("#getCode").html(resp);` before

Comment: This is the correct answer that I was looking for, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Try this one:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#getCode").html(data);
    jQuery("#getCodeModal").modal('show');
}
```

This should work :).

Comment: copied from above

Answer (score 2):

#### Write down the following code.

```
success: function(msg)
    {
        $("#getCodeModal").modal("show");
        $("#getCode").html(msg).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this happen when you include library jquery twice. check for that, maybe you include it in your index and then again unnecessarily in you partial page.

Answer (score 0):

after toggling the modal for the first time, you have to toggle it once again to "turni it off".. and on the success function toggle it and it will appear normally.
example:

```
$('#Modal').modal('toggle)  //this is the first time to toggle the modal
$('#Modal').modal('toggle)  //this is the second time "to turn it off"
success:function(){
$('#Modal').modal('toggle)  //this is the third time to "turn it on again"
}
```