# Bootstrap Modal On Php Submit using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Here I'm working on a simple withrawal page where users can select the amount they want to withdraw and submit afterwhich a bootstrap modal pops up confirming to the user that the request has been sent whilst updating the section in the db with the amount selected.

So far im facing no issues when user selects the amount and click on submit, the modal pops up but unfortunately the database is not updated, I can't fathom where i'm getting it wrong.

Here is the Php

```
<?php

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$withraw = "";
$withraw_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
      // Validate Withrawal
    if(empty(trim($_POST["withraw"]))){
        $withraw_err = "Please Choose a Amount.";     
    } else{   
            $withraw = trim($_POST["withraw"]);
            }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($withraw_err)){
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET withraw = (?) WHERE id = ".$id;

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_withraw);
            
            // Set parameters
           
            $param_withraw  = $withraw;
           
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
               echo "";
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Here is the code for the form im using.

```
<form  onsubmit="openModal()" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" id="myForm" >
           

              <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($withraw_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
               

                <div  style='width:50%;' class='selectt'><select name="withraw" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $withraw; ?>"><option >Choose Amount</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
        <option value="1000">1,000</option>
        <option value="1500">1,500</option>
        <option value="2000">2,000</option>
        <option value="2500">2,500</option>
                <option value="3000">3,000</option>
        <option value="3500">3,500</option>

</select>
        
        </div>
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $withraw_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
        
        
    


          <div class="form-group"  >
               <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-info btn-lg"   value="Submit">
                    Withraw  <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> </button> 
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default"  value="Reset"><i class="fas fa-redo"></i> Reset </button>
            </div>

        </form>
```

And I've added some javascript to load the bootstrap modal after the form is Submitted

```
<script>$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
                  });</script>
```

Here is where I'm completely lost as, when I remove the `e.preventDefault()` the form Updates the database row called **withraw** but the bootstrap does not load at all and I've been trying to set so that the bootstrap loads and the database row is updated as well I do not have more knowledge on how to tackle this situation as I read similar questions and some suggestions are to use Ajax but I have limited knowledge on how to do that.

*I didn't post the bootstrap because i don't see it necessarily its a normal Bootstrap modal setup*

Comment: Step through what is happening : 1) When someone clicks your submit button, the JS stops the form really being submitted. 2) The modal opens. 3) ... that's it. Your form is never actually submitted, so your PHP never runs. You need to rethink your flow a bit.  You said the modal should confirm the request has been sent, so it should actually open *after* your form has been sent and your PHP has run, right?  So you have 2 basic choices: let the form post normally, no JS, no modal, and at the end of your PHP redirect to a new page which opens a modal, *OR* ...

Comment: ... submit the form entirely via JS/AJAX, so the browser stays on the same page, and when that AJAX request completes, open the modal showing the results.  The first option is definitely easier if you are just learning, but there are plenty of examples here for both options.  Eg I just searched for "*php ajax open bootsrap modal on success*" and [the first result is a good example with code you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924551/how-to-open-bootstrap-modal-in-ajax-success).

Comment: Thank you, i already found a way to do it with a jQuery modal i found on this page https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/, thank you for your contribution